# How can I save a scene which consists of continuing text?

Tags: unity, c#

I am trying to make a simple book reading app. In scene, it will show only one word from the book every 0.5 seconds. What I want is, when I click pause then quit the game or just back to Main Menu and after returning to Main Menu, when I click to Read Book button, I want to continue from the word I left off. Below is a part of code which will be shown after clicking Read Book button.

```
void Start()
{
    textFile = (TextAsset)Resources.Load("FirstBook");
    string texts = textFile.text;

    StartCoroutine(Show(texts));
}
IEnumerator Show(string book)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);

    string[] splitArray = book.Split(' ');
    text = GameObject.FindWithTag("BookText").GetComponent<Text>();

    for (int i = 0; i < splitArray.Length; i++)
    {
        text.GetComponent<Text>().text = (splitArray[i]);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
    }
}
```

And below is what I used in my AppManager gameobject for pausing.

```
private bool paused;
public void ChangePaused()
{
    if (Time.timeScale == 1 && paused == false) 
    {
        Time.timeScale = 0; 
    }
    else
    {
        Time.timeScale = 1;
    }
}
```

My English is not that good so I am having difficulties to explain my problem, if you can't understand what I need I will try to explain better. Briefly, when I click pause it will keep the word I left off, and then I will back to Main Menu, I will click Read Book button and I will continue from the word I left off. How can I do this?

Comment: I would be quite annoyed with only seeing one word at a time when reading. A simple distraction and you miss part of a sentence. Speed reading techniques are also cross reading an entire paragraph without focus on a single word. You can store the index where you left in your player prefs and in your show function start at that index instead of 0

Comment: @Zibelas Thanks for the answer. You are right about reading with seeing only one word, but lets say it is just an app for self improvement :) That's what actually I asked, how will I store that index? How will I start from that index in show function? Can you show me simply how will I do that?

Comment: As an improvement, don't call text.GetComponent<Text>().text in the loop. Call it once before, store the reference and call that one in the loop

Comment: @Zibelas Thanks for the answer and suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Zibelas suggests I think what you're looking for is saving and loading a value and an easy way to do that is by using PlayerPrefs.

When pausing or OnApplicationQuit() `PlayerPrefs.SetInt($"{bookName}", currentWordIndex);`

when loading book `currentWordIndex = PlayerPrefs.GetInt($"{bookName}", 5);`

Comment: The default value on loading should be 0, not 5.

Comment: @aLaxCoder, that is what I was looking for, thank you.